# Is there a $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ function with an infinite number of strong local maxima and no local minimum?

Tags: analysis

Does there exist a function $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2) $ which has an infinite amount of strong local maxima and no local minimum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following function works
$$
f(x,y) = \cos(x)-y^2.
$$
Local strong (and global) maxima are at $y=0$ and $x=2k\pi$, and there is no local minimum.

Comment: Oh, that was too easy. i was looking for some talking about it $C^{\infty} $ class and using it in some description proof... Thank you!